# What's an elegant way to conditionally add a class to an HTML element in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I occasionally have to add a class to an html element based on a condition. The problem is I can't figure out a clean way of doing it. Here's an example of the stuff I've tried:

```
<div <%= if @status = 'success'; "class='ok'"; end %>>
   some message here
</div>
```

**OR**

```
<% if @status == 'success' %>
   <div class='success'>
<% else %>
   <div>
<% end %>
   some message here
</div>
```

I don't like the first approach because it's crowded looking and hard to read. I don't like the second approach because the nesting is screwed up. It'd be nice to put it in the model, (something like `@status.css_class`), but that doesn't belong there. What do most people do?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I use the first way, but with a slightly more succinct syntax:

```
<div class="<%= 'ok' if @status == 'success' %>">
```

Though usually you should represent success with boolean `true` or a numeric record ID, and failure with boolean `false` or `nil`.  This way you can just test your variable:

```
<div class="<%= 'ok' if @success %>">
```

A second form using the ternary `?:` operator is useful if you want to choose between two classes:

```
<div class="<%= @success ? 'good' : 'bad' %>">
```

Finally, you can use Rail's [record tag helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-div_for) such as `div_for`, which will automagically set your ID and class based on the record you give it.  Given a `Person` with id 47:

```
# <div id="person_47" class="person good">
<% div_for @person, class: (@success ? 'good' : 'bad') do %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 30):

## class_names (Rails 6.1+)

Rails 6.1 introduces a `class_names` view helper
to make it easier to conditionally apply class names
in views.

Before:

```rb
<div class="<%= item.for_sale? ? 'active' : '' %>">
```

After:

```rb
<div class="<%= class_names(active: item.for_sale?) %>">
```

More examples:

```rb
class_names("foo", "bar")
# => "foo bar"
class_names({ foo: true, bar: false })
# => "foo"
class_names(nil, false, 123, "", "foo", { bar: true })
# => "123 foo bar"
```

Sources:

- [Link to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37918).
- [Link to the `class_names` docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-class_names).

Answer (score 24):

## Avoiding logic in the views

The problem with the standard approach is that it requires logic in the form of `if` statements or ternaries in the view. If you have multiple conditional CSS classes mixed with default classes, then you need to put that logic into a string interpolation or ERB tag.

Here's an updated approach that avoids putting any logic into the views:

```
<div class="<%= class_string(ok: @success) %>">
   some message here
</div>
```

### `class_string` method

The `class_string` helper takes a hash with key/value pairs consisting of **CSS class name strings** and **boolean values**. The result of the method is a string of classes where the boolean value evaluated to true.

#### Sample Usage

```
class_names(foo: true, bar: false, baz: some_truthy_variable)
# => "foo baz"
```

#### Other Use Cases

This helper can be used within `ERB` tags or with Rails helpers such as `link_to`.

```
<div class="<%= class_string(ok: @success) %>">
   some message here
</div>

<% div_for @person, class: class_string(ok: @success) do %>
<% end %>

<% link_to "Hello", root_path, class: class_string(ok: @success) do %>
<% end %>
```

#### Either/Or Classes

For use cases where a ternary would be necessary (e.g. `@success ? 'good' : 'bad'`), pass an array where the first element is the class for `true` and the other is for `false`

```
<div class="<%= [:good, :bad] => @success %>">
```

### Inspired by React

This technique is inspired by an add-on called `classNames` (formerly known as `classSet`) from Facebook’s `React` front-end framework.

### Using in your Rails projects

As of now, the `class_names` function does not exist in Rails, but [this article](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/a-cleaner-way-to-set-multiple-conditional-css-classes-for-link-to.html?utm_source=stackoverflow) shows you how to add or implement it into your projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the content_for helper, especially if the DOM is located in a layout and you want to set the css class depending on the partial loaded.

On the layout:

```
%div{class: content_for?(:css_class) ? yield(:css_class) : ''}
```

On the partial:

```
- content_for :css_class do
    my_specific_class
```

That is it.

Comment: please don't use template engine example on generic question without the template engine tagged

Answer (score 0):

if you're using rails helpers you could use a ternary like this in the class attribute

```
<%= link_to "My Account", account_path, class: @account.present? ? 'dropdown-item' : 'dropdown-item disabled' %>
```

What this means is. if there is an @account object, then the class will be `dropdown-item`, otherwise the link will be disabled `dropdown-item disabled`