# Conditionally add a class to link_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to conditionally add the class "hidden" to a Rails link tag, depending on if "accepted == true".

If I weren't using a rails `link_to` I could do `<a href="#" class="foo bar <%= "hidden" if accepted == true %>" >`. How can I accomplish this inside a `link_to`?

```
<%= link_to "Accept Friend Request", 
    "#", 
    class: "btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block requestSent ???hidden???",
    disabled: true %>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it outside the `link_to`:

```
<% css_class = accepted ? "hidden" : "" %>
<%= link_to "Accept Friend Request", 
  "#", 
  class: "btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block requestSent #{css_class}",
  disabled: true %>
```

Answer (score 33):

If you use interpolation with #{}, anything you put between it is run as plain old Ruby code.
In this example you could add a conditional class in the string like this:

```
<%= link_to "Accept Friend Request", 
    "#", 
    class: "btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block requestSent #{'hidden' if accepted}",
    disabled: true %>
```

Just note that you should use single quotes around the class name 'hidden'.
Also note that when a variable represents a boolean value (true or false), you don't need to explicitly say `if accepted == true`. You can simply say `if accepted`.

Comment: Great, elegant and easiest solution. Tks!

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer IMO. For example if you have a navigation with 5 links in it and you want to  add a class to highlight the current_page, you can't do it with the accepted answer. But this answer works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a helper to build up the link as well:

```
def accept_friend_request_link
  classes = [:btn, :and_friends]
  if accepted
    classes << :hidden
  end
  link_to 'Accept Friend Request', '#', class: classes, disabled: true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I posted a similar answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41724128/1219460).

## A cleaner solution

The standard approach requires putting logic into the views and using string interpolation or moving things into a separate helper.

Here's an updated approach that avoids any of that:

```
<%= link_to "Accept Friend Request", 
    "#", 
    class: class_string("btn btn-success btn-sm ban-block requestSent" => true, hidden: accepted),
    disabled: true %>
```

### `class_string` method

The `class_string` helper takes a hash with key/value pairs consisting of **CSS class name strings** and **boolean values**. The result of the method is a string of classes where the boolean value evaluated to true.

#### Sample Usage

```
class_names("foo bar" => true, baz: false, buzz: some_truthy_variable)
# => "foo bar baz"
```

### Inspired by React

This technique is inspired by an add-on called `classNames` (formerly known as `classSet`) from Facebook’s `React` front-end framework.

### Using in your Rails projects

As of now, the `class_names` function does not exist in Rails, but [this article](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/a-cleaner-way-to-set-multiple-conditional-css-classes-for-link-to.html?utm_source=stackoverflow) shows you how to add or implement it into your projects.

Comment: As of Rails 6.1 (possibly earlier) the [token_list](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L327} method (aliased to class_names) does exactly this and I believe is a better solution to the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I've override the link_to to expect a `class_if` parameter, check it out:

```
def link_to(options = {}, html_options = {})
  if html_options.is_a?(Hash) && html_options.key?(:class_if)
    html_options[:class] <<
      (" #{html_options[:class_if][1].strip}") if html_options[:class_if][0]

    html_options.delete :class_if
  end

  super(options, html_options)
end
```

And usage:

`<%= link_to(my_path, class: "class1", class_if: [true_or_false?, 'class2']) %>`

I've just override one method, but a good refactor is to override all of described signatures here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

#### UPDATE

Another solution is:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def active_link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
    html_options ||= { class: '' }
    html_options[:class].concat('is-active') if options.match(controller_name)

    link_to(name, options, html_options, &block)
  end
end
```

And usage:

```
<%= active_link_to(my_path, 'My path') %>
```

This way, I got an "active status" even when is a custom route like: "my_path/help", "my_path/two".