# Instance variables in a while loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Ruby on Rails application that I am using to display some certification dates. I have the table row set up like so:

```
<tr class='<%= @row_class %>'>data_goes_here</tr>
```

and am using this code:

```
@trainings.each do |training| 

  %w{drivers_license a_plus network_plus server_plus}.each do |field_name| 
    if training[field_name] < 45.days.from_now
      if training[field_name] < 15.days.from_now
        @row_class = 'danger'
        break
      else 
        @row_class = 'warning'
        break
      end 
    elsif training[field_name] > 45.days.from_now && !@row_class
      @row_class = 'success'
    end
  end
end
```

to set an instance variable to the Twitter Bootstrap class name corresponding to the amount of time left before the certification expires. When I run a puts statement at the end of the each loop, it outputs the right text; but when I load the page, the only class name that gets passed is 'danger'.

I want the logic to work so if one of the certs is either warning or danger, it exits out of the loop and moves to the next user. The thought is, if the user has a cert coming up they should be marked with the danger or warning class, otherwise they should be marked with the success class.

Should I maybe define a variable in the model and assign the value to it, rather than trying to pass through an instance variable?

Comment: why don't you use conditional class in your view like http://stackoverflow.com/a/2626946/2563282

Comment: In every loop, you are resetting the instance variable. So in the view, it will have the last value set.

Comment: That is what I am noticing; how can I pass individual variables to the model on each loop?

Comment: Can you add the loop in the view file?

Comment: I had the loop in the view, but it was REALLY cluttered. Was trying to follow some best practices and move the logic out of the view, but it might be easiest to move it back in.

Comment: Well, my question was misleading. I wanted to see your view file code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Helper**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html)

As per the comments you'll be better setting the class as part of the loop (probably using a `helper` method):

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
Class ApplicationHelper
   def set_class(field_name, class= "success")
       %w{drivers_license a_plus network_plus server_plus}.each do |field_name| 
           case training[field_name]
              when < 45.days.from_now
                class_name = 'warning'
              when < 15.days.from_now
                class_name = 'danger'
           end
       end
       return class_name
   end
end

#app/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
<% @trainings.each do |training| %>
     <tr class='<%= set_class training %>'>data_goes_here</tr>
<% end %>
```

--

[**Scoping**](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope)

Something you may also wish to consider is the `scoping` of your variables. If you're setting variables within a loop, it's typically the case they will not be available outside it (likewise if you set within a function / method etc).

Although I'm not sure the specifics on `instance variables`, the idea of scoping is pretty consistent throughout all programming languages; you'll be best reading up on its implications

Comment: This one threw me for a loop, until after staring at it realized that class is a protected variable name. Changed that to class_name, and it was giving me an error in the case statement. Ended up going back to an if/then/else statement, and it works great! Thanks for the tip on scoping; though I am familiar from other languages, perhaps not as fluently as I hoped. Thanks!